# Android. Designing the background image of the app

Tags: android, image, screen-resolution

I am currently discussing a design scheme with a friend of mine who is a designer. And i don't know at what resolution i should tell him to make the background image. I was thinking of telling him to make a high-def image and then go from there, re-scale it for smaller device screen, but i don't know and am not able to find online which resolution is the highest.

Comment: designing background image for activity right?

Comment: yes, it's the main interface of the game. It's a static image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell him to check out [the Android design pages](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) and all the related links on that site. It tells everything you need to know about Android design principles.

Other link(s):

[Devices and Displays](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Quote from the Devices and Displays Page:

> **Strategies** 
>   So where do you begin when designing for multiple screens?
>   One approach is to work in the base standard (medium size, MDPI) and
>   scale it up or down for the other buckets. Another approach is to
>   start with the device with the largest screen size, and then scale
>   down and figure out the UI compromises you'll need to make on smaller
>   screens.

Comment: Ok, great. And what is your personal suggestion? At which resolution should i tell him to make it so it looks good on tables as well? Give me a number :) In fact two, height and wight :)

Comment: oh, i see. You just answered my question in the edit. :) ok, thanks. Now i just need to find out the largest screen size ;)

Answer (score 3):

For background image, design same image with different size for different resolution :

For LDPI : 240X300
    MDPI : 320X455
    XHDPI: 720X1233
    HDPI:  480 X 762

Basically start from ldpi with 240 and consecutively design image in multiplier of 1.5x

Answer (score 1):

Hi refer this site  [screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

and if you have more doubt in this ask me.